# Fix position: absolute element in a overflow: scroll element when scrolling

Tags: scroll, css-position, css

I want to accomplish a preview of an image gallery that is wider than the screen, using `overflow: scroll` (or auto).
To the right, a shadow that overlaps the last visible image should indicate that more images are visible to the right.

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SBdLg/

First, I thought: Easy, give that image gallery a `box-shadow: inset`. But that will be shown behind the images.
Now, with an overlapping `div` that has `position: absolute`, I reach the desired effect BUT the `box-shadow` also moves when scrolling to the right.

IMHO, this problem would also occur when using an image containing the shadow instead of the `div` on top.

Is the desired effect possible by CSS at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `position: relative` from the `outer` DIV and positioning the `shadow` precisely where you need it (this is the ugly bit) will help you achieve this.

Check the **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SBdLg/11/

Comment: Updated the demo to add a further outer DIV with position: relative so that you can move the gallery around without messing with the position of the shadow each time.

Comment: Thanks, removing the `position: relative` and adding one more `div` around it helped :)